# How to login and navigate in code with CefSharp

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I am using CefSharp in a WPF application and want to load a website, login and then navigate to a part of the same website. Loading the website and logging in is working fine. But when I try to navigate to a specific URL, I am not logged in anymore. This is not the case when I manually click on links in the CefSharp Browser Control. Here is what I basically do:

```cs
public class MainWindow
{
   public MainWindow()
   {
       Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings()
       {
            CachePath = "C:\\Users\\Documents\\CefCachePath"
       });
       InitializeComponent();
       AutoNavigation()
   }

   private async void AutoNavigation()
   {
       await InvokeBrowserActionAsync(browser, () => browser.Address = loginUrl);
       await InvokeBrowserActionAsync(browser, () => browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(loginScript);
       await InvokeBrowserActionAsync(browser, () => browser.Address = targetUrl);
   }

    public static Task InvokeBrowserActionAsync(ChromiumWebBrowser browser, Action action)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        EventHandler<NavStateChangedEventArgs> handler = null;
        handler += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (!args.IsLoading)
            {
                browser.NavStateChanged -= handler;
                tcs.TrySetResult(true);
            }
        };
        browser.NavStateChanged += handler;
        action.Invoke();
        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Does the executing user have write access to the cache directory? Is the path you provided the real path your using?

Comment: Does the `browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(loginScript)` call cause the browser to fire the `NavStateChanged` event?

Comment: I run the application from Visual Studio as Administrator. The path exists and I can access the cache directory.

Comment: `NavStateChanged` is called in `browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(loginScript)`

Answer (score 0):

Without having more specific info I would drop down to comparing what communication happens on the wire e.g. with a tool like [Fiddler](https://chocolatey.org/packages/fiddler4) for your manual and `AutoNavigation()` driven cases. Look for missing `Authorization:` headers etc.

Comment: I just figured out with the help of Fiddler that the targetUrl simply does not preserve the authentication.

Comment: I'm a bit unsure what targetUrl you are talking about. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/search?utf8=✓&q=targetUrl ... Could you spell out where exactly in the flow you are missing what? Better than we have to guess too much :-)